# Line too long for setting up variable

Tags: ansible, lint

This is my Ansible task:

```yaml
- name: get the custom job id
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    custom_job_id: >
      "{{ train_custom_image_unmanaged_response.stderr_lines |select('search', 'describe') |list |regex_search('.*/customJobs/(\\d+)', '\\1') |first }}"
  when: "(gcs_model_list.stdout is not defined) or ('saved_model.pb' not in gcs_model_list.stdout)"
```

I am getting *"line too long"* as Ansible lint error for `custom_job_id` line.
Any idea how can I break it down in smaller parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using YAML [multi lines syntaxes](https://yaml-multiline.info), as you started doing it.

With this syntax, the indentation is what is defining a block, so, as long as you are indented inward of the fact name `custom_job_id`, all the following code is considered as being the expression that is going to be assigned to that fact.

For example:

```yaml
- name: get the custom job id
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    custom_job_id: >-
      {{ 
        train_custom_image_unmanaged_response.stderr_lines 
        | select('search', 'describe') 
        | list 
        | regex_search('.*/customJobs/(\d+)', '\1') 
        | first 
      }}
  when: >- 
    gcs_model_list.stdout is not defined 
    or 'saved_model.pb' not in gcs_model_list.stdout
```

---

Here is a playbook complying with the Ansible linting demonstrating this:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:
    - name: Get the custom job id
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        custom_job_id: >-
          {{
            train_custom_image_unmanaged_response.stderr_lines
            | select('search', 'describe')
            | list
            | regex_search('.*/customJobs/(\d+)', '\1')
            | first
          }}
      when: >-
        gcs_model_list.stdout is not defined
        or 'saved_model.pb' not in gcs_model_list.stdout
      vars:
        train_custom_image_unmanaged_response:
          stderr_lines:
            - foo
            - bar
            - describe - /customJobs/123
            - baz
        gcs_model_list:

    - name: Display `custom_job_id`
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: custom_job_id
```

Which yields:

```
PLAY [localhost] **********************************************************

TASK [Get the custom job id] **********************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Display `custom_job_id`] ********************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  custom_job_id: '123'
```